# Adding a dragging animation using hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've just finished building my slider with touch events using hammer.js. Right now I'm trying to figure out how can I add a dragging effect on my slider. Basically the concept is once I swipe left or right before releasing my finger from the element or screen, it will drag the slider 30px to the left or right before sliding to the next slide

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


 $('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     // store variable relevent to clicked slider
     var sliderWrapper      = $(this).closest('.slider-wrapper'),
      slideItems         = sliderWrapper.find('.slide-items'),
         slider             = sliderWrapper.find('.slider'),
         currentSlide       = sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide');

     // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
     if( currentSlide > 0 ) {
   // Decremement current slide
   currentSlide--;
   // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
   slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
   // Update data-slide attribute
   sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
     }
 });

 $('.next').on('click', function(e) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     // store variable relevent to clicked slider

  var sliderWrapper      = $(this).closest('.slider-wrapper'),
      slideItems         = sliderWrapper.find('.slide-items'),
      slider             = sliderWrapper.find('.slider'),
      totalSlides        = slideItems.length,
      currentSlide       = sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide');

  // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
  if( currentSlide < totalSlides - 1 ) {
      // Increment current slide
      currentSlide++;
      // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
      slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
      // Update data-slide attribute
      sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
  }
 })

 $('.slider-wrapper').each(function(){

     // create a simple instance
     // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
     var direction;
     var mc = new Hammer(this),
         itemLength = $(this).find('.slide-items').length,
         count = 0,
         slide = $(this);


  var sliderWrapper      = slide,
      slideItems         = sliderWrapper.find('.slide-items'),
      slider             = sliderWrapper.find('.slider'),
      totalSlides        = slideItems.length,
      currentSlide       = sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide');

     
     mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
       direction = ev.type;
     });

     mc.on("panend", function(ev) {
      if(direction === "panleft") {
             console.log('panleft');

    // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
    if( currentSlide < totalSlides - 1 ) {
        // Increment current slide
        currentSlide++;
        // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
        slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
        // Update data-slide attribute
        sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
    }
      }

      if(direction === "panright") {
             console.log('right');

       // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
       if( currentSlide > 0 ) {
     // Decremement current slide
     currentSlide--;
     // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
     slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
     // Update data-slide attribute
     sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
       }
      }
     });
 });



});

$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.slider-wrapper').each(function() {
    var slideItems = $(this).find('.slide-items'),
    items = slideItems.length,
    sliderBox = $(this).find('.slider'),
    sliderWrapperWidth = $(this).width();

    slideItems.outerWidth( sliderWrapperWidth / 2 );
    sliderBox.width( slideItems.outerWidth() * items  );
  });

});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
 v2.0 | 20110126
 License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.container .slider-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden; }

.container .slider-wrapper .slider {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden; }

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e5d0d0; }

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div p {
  color: purple; }

.container .slider-wrapper .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: beige;
  padding: 10px 0; }

.container .slider-wrapper .buttons div {
  background-color: cyan; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget ex mi. Etiam a vestibulum ligula, id porta dui. Duis in iaculis quam. Integer aliquam justo nec nibh consequat vulputate.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget ex mi. Etiam a vestibulum ligula, id porta dui. Duis in iaculis quam. Integer aliquam justo nec nibh consequat vulputate.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified something from your code. Is this similar what you are trying to do??

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


 $('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     // store variable relevent to clicked slider
     var sliderWrapper      = $(this).closest('.slider-wrapper'),
      slideItems         = sliderWrapper.find('.slide-items'),
         slider             = sliderWrapper.find('.slider'),
         currentSlide       = sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide');

     // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
     if( currentSlide > 0 ) {
   // Decremement current slide
   currentSlide--;
   // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
   slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
   // Update data-slide attribute
   sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
     }
 });

 $('.next').on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     // store variable relevent to clicked slider

  var sliderWrapper      = $(this).closest('.slider-wrapper'),
      slideItems         = sliderWrapper.find('.slide-items'),
      slider             = sliderWrapper.find('.slider'),
      totalSlides        = slideItems.length,
      currentSlide       = sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide');

  // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
  if( currentSlide < totalSlides - 1 ) {
      // Increment current slide
      currentSlide++;
      // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
      slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
      // Update data-slide attribute
      sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
  }
 })

 $('.slider-wrapper').each(function(){

     // create a simple instance
     // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
     var direction;
     var mc = new Hammer(this),
         itemLength = $(this).find('.slide-items').length,
         count = 0,
         slide = $(this);


  var sliderWrapper      = slide,
      slideItems         = sliderWrapper.find('.slide-items'),
      slider             = sliderWrapper.find('.slider'),
      totalSlides        = slideItems.length,
      currentSlide       = sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide');
    
    var dragDist = 40;
   var dist = 0;
    var curPosition = 0;
    var toPosition = 0;
      
     mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
       direction = ev.type;
        
        // modified
        dist = ev.deltaX;
        var maxDist = Math.min(dragDist, dist);
        curPosition = currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth();
        toPosition = curPosition + maxDist*-1;
        slider.css({'right': toPosition + 'px'});
     });

     mc.on("panend", function(ev) {
      
        slider.css({'right': curPosition + 'px'});
      
        if( Math.abs(dist) <= dragDist ){
          
          return;
        }
      
      if(direction === "panleft") {
             console.log('pan left');

    // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
    if( currentSlide < totalSlides - 1 ) {
        // Increment current slide
        currentSlide++;
        // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
        slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
        // Update data-slide attribute
        sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
    }
      }

      if(direction === "panright") {
             console.log('pan right');

       // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
       if( currentSlide > 0 ) {
     // Decremement current slide
     currentSlide--;
     // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
     slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
     // Update data-slide attribute
     sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
       }
      }
     });
 });



});

$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.slider-wrapper').each(function() {
    var slideItems = $(this).find('.slide-items'),
    items = slideItems.length,
    sliderBox = $(this).find('.slider'),
    sliderWrapperWidth = $(this).width();

    slideItems.outerWidth( sliderWrapperWidth / 2 );
    sliderBox.width( slideItems.outerWidth() * items  );
  });

});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
 v2.0 | 20110126
 License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.container .slider-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden; }

.container .slider-wrapper .slider {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden; }

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e5d0d0; }

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div p {
  color: purple; }

.container .slider-wrapper .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: beige;
  padding: 10px 0; }

.container .slider-wrapper .buttons div {
  background-color: cyan; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget ex mi. Etiam a vestibulum ligula, id porta dui. Duis in iaculis quam. Integer aliquam justo nec nibh consequat vulputate.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget ex mi. Etiam a vestibulum ligula, id porta dui. Duis in iaculis quam. Integer aliquam justo nec nibh consequat vulputate.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```